# Angular 2 component function call

Tags: angular

I want function call from component.

app.component.html

```
<div class="side">
<app-menu></app-menu>
</div>
<div class="page">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

}
```

How to Call '`<app-menu></app-menu>`' in Function ?

app-menu (menu.component.ts)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class MenuComponent {
  addItem(index: number, heading: string, route: string): void {
  }
    groups: Array<any> = [];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you try to accomplish.
My guess

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(MenuComponent) menu:MenuComponent;

  title = 'app works!';

  // can't be called before the `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle callback.
  foo() {
    this.menu.addItem(1, "heading foo", "some route");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank U!! :) LOLLLLLLL